# Chrome extension doesn't work if I upload a local content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension that I load from my computer. The `extension` folder contains 2 files, `manifest.json` and `content.js` like this:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "0.0",
  "description": "My first extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://my_new_website.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "./content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://my_website/content_file.js');
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Now, I want to upload the `content_file.js` from my computer instead of `https://my_website/`. So, I replaced the following line:

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://my_website/content_file.js');
```

with

```
let image = require("path_to/content_file.js");
script.setAttribute('src', image);
```

But my Chrome extension didn't work the same as the first case. What am I doing wrong? Isn't the `image` command sending the same information as the online `src` file? Thank you.

Comment: Simply copy `content_file.js` over your current `content.js`.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, so I should remove all 4 lines in `content.js` and replace it with the code in `content_file.js`, right?